# Unable to match all required fields. invoice2data

Tags: python-3.x, yaml

I'm trying to  create templates and have the data with invoice2data but that gives me this error

```
regexp for field amount didn't match
regexp for field amount_untaxed didn't match
regexp for field date didn't match
Unable to match all required fields. The required fields are: ['date', 'amount', 'invoice_number', 'issuer']. Output contains the following fields: ['vat', 'issuer', 'currency', 'invoice_number'].
```

I searched on my template template.yaml and i have all these fields

there is my template:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
issuer: Online SAS / Scaleway
fields:
  amount: (Total.*)\w+
  amount_untaxed: (Total.*)\w+
  date: (Date.*)\w+
  invoice_number: Facture n\W\s+(\d+)
  static_vat: FR35433115904
keywords:
  - Sosh
  - Orange
  - Votre facture mobile
options:
  currency: EUR
  date_formats:
    - '%B %d, %Y'
  decimal_separator: ','
```

I tried with a second example "pdf2.pdf" and it gives me

```
Syntax Error (69926): No current point in closepath
Syntax Error (69950): No current point in closepath
Syntax Error (69970): No current point in closepath
```

I searched on internet and i didn't see any answer.
Can someone explains me the problem

Thanks for your answer and sorry for my english.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show the command(s) you execute and your input. Without seeing your input, it remains unclear whether your template is at fault or the input is. In any case, `(Total.*)\w+` does not seem to make sense, why would you have the Text `Total` as part of the value and why should the value contain any kind of characters after `Total`? A backtracking regex engine will match this with the largest string it finds that is followed by one character matching `\w`.

Comment: thanks! i jhave found my error!  you were right the '(w+)' had no sense, regex are quite complicated :)